# CAN bus cable-termination mismatch

Tags: can, termination

I am trying to change the CAN cables alone to Cat 6 cables (which has 100 ohm characteristic impedance). The existing cable has 120 ohm impedance. By making this change to Cat 6 cables, I am trying to find out if there would be any issue with CAN signal integrity because the PCB transceivers remain the same with 120 ohm terminations in them.

Comment: What is the (total) length of the cable(s)? What is the bit rate on the CAN bus?

Answer (score 1):

That’s not that bad a mismatch. *Unless* you are already at an extremely marginal situation, it shouldn’t have any impact.

To see that via theory, when the bit wave reaches a terminator, I and V are balanced around 100 ohms, a 1:100 ratio. Suddenly the terminator is forcing a 1:120 ratio and that mismatch will cause reflections of the wave. That’s a mismatch by about 1/6th, so if you’ve got 30% margin you’re still good.

Empirically, if you do have a problem you can add 600 ohm resistors to the *two* (and only two!) existing terminators  to make them effectively 100ohms.